# UIPageViewController in XIB Error

Tags: ios, exception, uipageviewcontroller

I have a subclassed view controller and in Interface Builder I want a subview of the VC's view to be a UIPageViewController's view. I set the UIPageViewController's datasource to File's Owner and the view property to the subview of my VC. Can this functionality be achieved? or I can't use the UIPageVC in that way? Most of the examples are for storyboards and not the old VC pushed by NavigationController way. I get this exception '[UIView invalidatePageViewController]'.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem: programmatic setup, Nav VC, calling a subclassed pageviewcontroller, upon popping back to the navcontroller I am getting:   [UIView invalidatePageViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e81600

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen to me when I had a UIViewController as my root view - and my UIViewController had an attribute defined as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
```

My IBoutlet was also connected to a UIPageViewController in my xib.

The solution: Remove the IBoutlet and disconnect the UIPageViewController from my xib

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
```

Maybe the crash is related to 'there should only be one view controller per view'

Also, in the 'viewdidload' if you do
    _pageViewController.view = _apageView;

where _apageView is in your UIViewController as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *apageView;
```

This will also cause the same crash to happen - therefore you would need to do:

```
[_apageView addSubview:_pageController.view];
```

Then the crash shouldn't happen.